# Comparator implementation with compare() methods

Tags: sorting, customization, comparator

Here my class name is MyComparator2 but how can I use it here as a methods or object( am not sure ) MyComparator2() in another class name ComparaterDemo to define customized sorting . Can any one help to to make it clear regarding how one class can be used on another ??Thanks in advance

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class ComparaterDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<Integer> treeSetCOllection = new TreeSet<Integer>(new MyComparator2());
    treeSetCOllection.add(900);
    treeSetCOllection.add(10);
    treeSetCOllection.add(40);
    treeSetCOllection.add(100);
    treeSetCOllection.add(350);
    System.out.println(treeSetCOllection);

}
}

class MyComparator2 implements Comparator{
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2){
        Integer objectNumber1 = (Integer)obj1;
        Integer objectNumber2 = (Integer)obj2;
        if(objectNumber1<objectNumber2) return 1;
        else if (objectNumber1>objectNumber2) return -1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is that you are constructing the `TreeSet` with the specified `Comparator`. How this works is, for each element added using the `add()` method, it will automatically sort the set. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29),

Comment: thank you Zymus but only thing if i want to apply customized sorting as I wants my data to print in descending order in compare to ascending order. MyComparator2() used here is a default constructor that implements comparator.here am confused is here am calling two constructor at once-- new Treeset (new MyComparator2());

Comment: Yes, what you're doing is essentially: 
`MyComparator2 comparator = new MyComparator2(); TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(comparator);` And if you want to access the values in a descending order, you can simply use `TreeSet#descendingSet()` found at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#descendingSet%28%29

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your class visible to other classes you need to specify its visibility.  The three types of visibility in Java (I assume that's what you're using) are:

**public**

**private**

**protected**

They are defined as follows:

**Public** means that that class is visible to all classes regardless of where the file is located.

**Private** classes are classes inside of classes.  For example, if MyComparator2 was defined inside of the ComparaterDemo class then ComparaterDemo could see it, but no other classes could.

**Protected** classes function the same as private classes except subclasses can also access them.  So if MyComparator2 was defined inside of ComparaterDemo and SubComparaterDemo subclassed ComparaterDemo then SubComparaterDemo could access MyComparator2.  In this example, no other classes except for ComparaterDemo and its subclasses could see it.

In your question, MyComparator2 is set to protected by default.  If you change the line: "class MyComparator2 implements Comparator" to "public class MyComparator2 implements Comparator" you should have no more problems.

I hope this answers your question